# Initialization of list while json parsing

Tags: c#

**my json string is:**

```
{"actList" : [{"activityName":"com.todoroo.astrid.activity.TaskListActivity", "pageId": 1, "webviewActivity": false },{"activityName":"com.todoroo.astrid.activity.TaskEditActivity", "pageId": 2, "webviewActivity": false },{"activityName":"com.todoroo.astrid.actfm.CommentsActivity", "pageId": 3, "webviewActivity": false },{"activityName":"com.todoroo.astrid.actfm.ActFmLoginActivity", "pageId": 4, "webviewActivity": false },{"activityName":"com.todoroo.astrid.actfm.ActFmGoogleAuthActivity", "pageId": 5, "webviewActivity": false }]}
```

**class generated:**

```
public class ActList
{
    public string activityName { get; set; }
    public int pageId { get; set; }
    public bool webviewActivity { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<ActList> actList { get; set; }
}
```

when I try to access count by creating an instance like

```
RootObject obj = new RootObject();
Console.WriteLine(obj.actList.count);
```

it throws "**System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'**".

and when I modify class RootObject as

```
public class RootObject
{
  public List<ActList> actList=new List<ActList>();
}
```

then actlist.count returns 0.

what may be issue? I think I am not initializing list correctly.

Comment: You are not deserializing json string anywhere in your code. what you are doing is creating an empty list, what do you expect the count to be ?

Comment: So, where are you deserializing your JSON?

Comment: To deserialize the json use a framework like [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json): `var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(yourJsonString);`

Comment: if I have more than 1 variable in Rootobject class like "  public bool autoEnabled { get; set; }
        public List<ActList> actList { get; set; }"  then I have to deserialize once only I think,,,,,,,,I have not to deserialize for list separately

Comment: @VikashKumar: I don't understand your comment. No-one is suggesting you deserialize multiple times. Your JSON contains the list, and would presumably contain the `autoEnabled` value as well. So just deserialize to `RootObject` and all would be fine. (I'd strongly recommend renaming your properties to follow .NET naming conventions though; decorate them with attributes to indicate the expected JSON name.)

Comment: done thanks all for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like [Newtonsoft Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and do the deserialization

Try following

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
Console.WriteLine(obj.actList.Count);
```

Here "Count" should be like this, not "count"

Comment: if I have more than 1 variable in Rootobject class like " public bool autoEnabled { get; set; } public List<ActList> actList { get; set; }" then I have to deserialize once only I think,,,,,,,,I have not to deserialize for list separately